# Class Variables and Methods not Available to other class

Tags: c#, .net, class, variables, methods

I am getting this problem. I created a class in a Windows Forms Application - WFA. It has one namespace as XmlParsing. it has two classes, both public, one partial. One class is named as myWindow; this is also public partial class. The other is MemberFunction class; this is public only. It has few strings and simple get n set methods. Now the issue is none of the variables and get n set methods are showing up in the myWindow class.

Please help. This is how I am doing stuff:

```
namespace XmlParsing
{
    MemberFunction Class is here

    myWindow Class is Here
}
```

Both are completely separate. I don't get where m running out of my limits.

Comment: Could you add some more detail to your code? That will help us pinpoint what problems you are having.

Comment: Please put a more complete example. Perhaps you can create a version of the code with the bare minimum needed to cause this problem

Answer (score 2):

Make sure your properties/variables are defined as `public` in your class. For example

```
class myWindow 
{
     public string MyProperty { get; set; }
     public int Field1;
     public static int StaticField;
}
```

Also if they are non-static members then you have to create an object of the class to access them.

```
myWindow objMyWindow = new myWindow();
objMyWindow.MyProperty = "Some string";
objMyWindow.Field1 = 10;
```

If you have defined a field as static you can access it against class name as well, like:

```
myWindow.StaticField = 100; //accessing static field
```

You may consider renaming your class and use [Pascal case](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x2dbyw72%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) for class names.